# How to multiply two measures prior to aggregation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have two measures. The first is amount, and the second consist of values -1,0 and 1, so table looks like this:

```
Amount   Sign
--------------
400      -1
200       1
300       0
```

Result I want to get is `400*(-1) + 200*1 + 300*0 = -200`, but I am getting `(400+200+300)*(-1+1+0) = 0`

This is my calculated member:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Result]
  AS
[Measures].[Sign]*[Measures].[Amount]
select 
[Measures].[Result] on 0,
[Time].[Time].members on 1
from [MyCube]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you SSAS project, go to the datasource view, for the underlying fact table add a NamedCalculation. In that do the multiplication that you explained. Now in the Cube add that as a measure. It will behave exactly like you want it to behave.