# Sum-up and then calculate vs. calculate and then sum-up (SSAS-MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a cube in SSAS multidimensional mode.

I have created a calculating measure in visual studio called "Total Cost". The formula is:

```
[Measures].[Unit Cost]*[Measures].[Qty]
```

It is in the lowest level of granularity (i.e. - the transnational level information has these fields).

The formula works well, as long as I present the data in this same level of granularity (for example, when I create a pivot and the rows are transaction IDs - like the source file)

However, when I present it in an aggregate format (for example - by customer) - then instead of making the calculation and then sum it up, it sum up and then calculate.

Here is what I expected:
[Expected results vs. What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQHmL.png)

My understanding, that this is regardless a (correct/incorrect) hierarchy structure. In other words, I expected this calculation to work even without defining any hierarchy between the transaction ID level and the customer level.

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SSAS project ->datasource view, you need to add a named calculation. This would be                 "[Unit Cost]*[Qty]". Now add this named calculation as a Measure in your Cube. This do the job. This problem was already addressed in the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554284/how-to-multiply-two-measures-prior-to-aggregation/53558733#53558733